# Proving that $\tilde{T}$ is 1-1 & onto

Tags: linear-algebra, equivalence-relations

For $v \in V$, we use $[v]$ to denote the equivalence class containing $v$. Let $T: V \to W$ be a linear map. Defining the linear map $\tilde{T}: V/\ker(T) \rightarrow \operatorname{im}(T)$ with the formula $\tilde{T}([v]) = T(v)$, we want to show that $\tilde{T}$ is 1-1 & onto.

If $v \sim w \in \ker(T)$, then we know $T(v - w) = 0$, which also shows that $T(v) = T(w)$. I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any help would be very appreciated. I'm pretty sure this has bearing on the first isomorphism theorem, but again I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, this has relation with the first isomorphism theorem, because it is!

Comment: I'm really having a hard time understanding the first isomorphism theorem (at least from online resources) as I have not seen it taught in class. Could you please help me with that? All the online sources seems to work around with groups, which I've never learned about.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to prove is actually the first isomorphism theorem! You have correctly shown that $\tilde{T}$ is a well-defined mapping. Now we need to show that $\tilde{T}$ is also a linear map that is both injective (1-1) and surjective (onto). The linearity of $\tilde{T}$ is actually pretty easy to verify:
$$\tilde{T}([v]+[w]) = \tilde{T}([v+w]) = T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w) = \tilde{T}([v]) + \tilde{T}([w])$$
and
$$\tilde{T}(a\cdot[v]) = \tilde{T}([av]) = T(av) = a\cdot T(v) = a \cdot \tilde{T}([v])$$
For injectivity, let $[v] \in \ker \tilde{T}$. Then $\tilde{T}([v]) = T(v) = 0$ and therefore $v \in \ker T$ which implies that $[v] = [0]$. Since $\ker \tilde{T} = \{[0]\}$ we conclude that $\tilde{T}$ is injective.

For surjectivity, notice that for every $w \in \text{im}T$ we have some $v \in V$ such that $T(v)=w$. By definition, $\tilde{T}([v]) = T(v) = w$ which of course gives us the surjectivity of $\tilde{T}$.

We have just proven that there exists an isomorphism $V/\ker T \simeq \text{im}T$ which is exactly what the first isomorphism theorem states.